# Missing Step In Sequoyah documentation for JNI debugging How to create process file for C++ Debugging

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am following steps in document

http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/documentation/native_debug.php

It says to create a C++ Debug Configuration pointing to a process file?  How should this process file be created.  This step is not described.

Update: This step does appear in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to run ndk-gdb from the Android project directory. This will create the process file. Perhaps there are some particular arguments needed ...